# Como selecionar uma opção em um <select> e carregar dados relacionados em outro?

Tags: php, javascript, html-select

Gostaria de selecionar uma opção de um `<select>` e preencher o outro `<select>` com conteúdo relacionado.

Só vou conseguir fazer isso com as informações guardadas em banco banco de dados ou tem como fazer com array? Como posso fazer isso?

**HTML**

```
<select id='cursos'>
    <option>curso 1</option>
    <option>curso 2</option>
</select>

<select id='atividades'>
    <!-- carregar options ao selecionar uma opção no select anterior -->
</select>
```

Comment: É PHP e MySQL????

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Exemplo 1:**

*Tabelas relacionadas (ufs e cidades)*

```
//ufs
CREATE TABLE `ufs` (
  `ufid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uf` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ufid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
//cidades
CREATE TABLE `cidades` (
  `cidadeid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ufid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cidadeid`),
  KEY `ufpkufid_idx` (`ufid`),
  CONSTRAINT `ufpkufid` FOREIGN KEY (`ufid`) REFERENCES `ufs` (`ufid`) 
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Com essas tabelas criadas e preenchidas crie no [PHP](http://www.php.net/) uma conexão com seu banco de dados [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/), com [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) dessa forma:

```
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=generics;host=localhost', 'root', 'senha', 
                    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
```

- **dbname** = "nome do seu banco de dados"
- **host**   = "ip de conexao do seu banco de dados ou localhost se banco for local (127.0.0.1)"
- aonde está **'root'** é o usuário do banco e **'senha'** é a senha desse usuário para conectar no seu banco.

Esse conexão vai ser utilizada em todo exemplo, então, crie um arquivo separado com o nome de `conn.php` (o nome pode ser de sua preferência), e coloque o código no mesmo.

*PHP*

**Nome:** *combos.php*

```
<?php include 'conn.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Combos Dependentes</title>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="CmbUF"> 
    <option value="">Selecione a UF</option>
    <?php
        foreach($pdo->query('SELECT ufid, uf FROM ufs order by uf') as $row){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['ufid'].'">'.$row['uf'].'</option>';
        }       
    ?>
</select>
<select id="CmbCidade"> 
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#CmbUF').change(function(e) {
            $('#CmbCidade').empty();
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.post('call_cidades.php', {ufid:id}, function(data){
                var cmb = '<option value="">Selecione a Cidade</option>';
                $.each(data, function (index, value){
                    cmb = cmb + '<option value="' + value.cidadeid + '">' + value.cidade + '</option>';;
                });
                $('#CmbCidade').html(cmb);
            }, 'json');
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

A mesma renderizada pelo navegador ficará assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O carregamento da UF já acontece por padrão com o carregamento dessa página, ao clicar na UF e escolher alguma na lista a mesma dispara um evento no select ([onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)) e enviará informações de requisição Ajax para o servidor. Tudo isso usando o [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) com [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

O arquivo PHP responsável em receber tal requisição tem esse layout:

**Nome:** *call_cidades.php*

```
<?php       
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) && $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] === "XMLHttpRequest"){
        include 'conn.php';
        $ufid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ufid', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        if ($ufid){
            $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT cidadeid, cidade FROM cidades where ufid=? ORDER BY cidade');
            $query->bindParam(1, $ufid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->execute();          
            echo json_encode($query->fetchAll());
            return;
        }       
    }
    echo NULL;
```

Após seu processamento, o mesmo retornar um [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) nesse formato:

```
[{"cidadeid":"5","0":"5","cidade":"BOM JARDIM","1":"BOM JARDIM"},{"cidadeid":"4","0":"4","cidade":"CAMBUCI","1":"CAMBUCI"},{"cidadeid":"3","0":"3","cidade":"RIO DE JANEIRO","1":"RIO DE JANEIRO"}]
```

Esse [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) vai ser trabalhado no [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) do [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) carregando o select CmbCidade, e qualquer escolha será carregado a lista referente aquela UF.

---

**Exemplo 2:**

Utilizando o plugin [Jquery CascadeSelect](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-cascade/) podemos ter o mesmo efeito do *Exemplo 1*, fazendo alterações minimas no `Combo.php` e `Call_Cidades.php`. Esse plugin utiliza [HTTP Método](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) `GET` e tem uma peculiaridade no retorno da informação (utiliza `label` e `value` para o preenchimento do `select` dependente no formato [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/))

*PHP*

**Nome:** *combo2.php*

```
<?php include 'conn.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Combos Dependentes</title>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--https://code.google.com/p/jquery-cascade/-->
<script src="jquery.cascade-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="CmbUF"> 
    <option value="">Selecione a UF</option>
    <?php
        foreach($pdo->query('SELECT ufid, uf FROM ufs order by uf') as $row){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['ufid'].'">'.$row['uf'].'</option>';
        }       
    ?>
</select>
<select id="CmbCidade"> 
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#CmbUF').cascade({
                source: "call_cidades2.php",
                cascaded: "CmbCidade",
                extraParams: { ufid: function(){ return $('#CmbUF').val();  } },
                dependentLoadingLabel: "Carregando Cidades ...",
                dependentNothingFoundLabel: "Não existe cidades",
                dependentStartingLabel: "Selecione a UF",
        });     
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Nome:** *call_cidades2.php*

```
<?php           
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) && $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] === "XMLHttpRequest"){        
        include 'conn.php';
        $ufid = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ufid', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        if ($ufid){
            $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT cidadeid as value, cidade as label FROM cidades where ufid=? ORDER BY cidade');
            $query->bindParam(1, $ufid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->execute();          
            echo json_encode($query->fetchAll());
            return;
        }       
    }
    echo NULL;
```

Obs: No `Call_Cidades.php` tem vários detalhes de mudança:

- `INPUT_GET` agora como forma de resgatar as informações no `filter_input`.
- na SQL agora está renomeado para `cidadeid as value` e `cidade as label` para padronizar o retorno de acordo com o plugin

*Acredito que no **Exemplo 2** fica mais tranquilo as alterações*.

Comment: isso mesmo que eu quero :D
obrigada :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$dados = $conex->query('SELECT nome, email FROM cadastros');
while ($linha = $dados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
  echo $linha->nome . ' - ' . $linha->email;
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Esse código é uma dúvida?