# Carregar valores após mudança do comboBox(Select)

Tags: javascript, php

Como ao selecionar o valor de um `combobox` na mesma hora alguns `textbox` sejam carregados? É uma edição de usuário. Sei que isso deve ser feito em JS, alguém poderia me informar como?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14646/como-selecionar-uma-opcao-em-um-select-e-carregar-dados-relacionados-em-outro/14668#14668 já possui algo parecido

Comment: Tentou utilizar ajax? Ou pode carregar todas as informações do banco antes e só preencher os elementos com o js.

Comment: Você já tentou fazer alguma coisa? São textos fixos ou informações dinâmicas? Quanto mais completo você for na sua pergunta melhor será a resposta obtida.

Comment: Leandro, as textbox que pretende carregar têm dados de uma base de dados ou quer somente novos textbox para serem preenchidos pelo usuário?

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que o valor do menu dropdown deve ser capturado e, a partir dele, o script deve decidir o que fazer, montei o exemplo a seguir. É só adaptar para as suas necessidades.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Atualização com JS puro</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="selecao">
            <option value="1ª opção" selected>Primeira opção aqui</option>
            <option value="2ª opção">Segunda opção aqui</option>
            <option value="personalizar">Personalizar</option>
        </select>
        <input id="caixa1" type="text" />
        <div id="div_personalizar" style="visibility: hidden;">
            <input type="radio" name="radios" checked /> Opção padrão
            <input type="radio" name="radios" /> Opção escondida
        </div>
        <script>
            // Selecionamos o menu dropdown, que possui os valores possíveis:
            var menu_dropdown = document.getElementById("selecao");

            // Requisitamos que a função handler (que copia o valor selecionado para a caixa de texto) [...]
            // [...] seja executada cada vez que o valor do menu dropdown mude:
            menu_dropdown.addEventListener("change", function(){

                // Como este código é executado após cada alteração, sempre obtemos o valor atualizado:
                var valor_selecionado = menu_dropdown.options[menu_dropdown.selectedIndex].value;

                // Altere este código se desejar resultados mais complexos:
                if(valor_selecionado == "personalizar"){
                    document.getElementById("div_personalizar").style.visibility = "";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("caixa1").value = valor_selecionado;
                    document.getElementById("div_personalizar").style.visibility = "hidden";
                }

            });
            // Opcional: copia o valor inicial. Sem essa linha, a caixa de texto inicia vazia.
            document.getElementById("caixa1").value = menu_dropdown.options[menu_dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```