# Como alterar valor da URL, com as informações retidas no Select/Option

Tags: javascript, php, url

Eu uso isso por conta que estou desenvolvendo um sistema de E-Commercer, mais o cliente quer que os produtos estejam em ComboBox com Select. Ate ai esta tudo correto, minha dificuldade esta em fazer a alteração da URL, conforme o 'produto' selecionado no `<SELECT>/<OPTION>`

Eu preciso que a URL seja alterada conforme os item escolhido no Select, este Select faz uma consulta no banco de dados que apresenta os produtos nos

Eu estou conseguindo pegar as informações quando escolho determinado OPTION do SELECT:
Meu problema é fazer alterar a URL.

Segue o Codigo.

//Pego os valores do OPTION e passa a uma variavel.

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>
     function PegarValores(){
    pd_nome = document.getElementById('produto_nome').options[document.getElementById('produto_nome').selectedIndex].text;
    pd_id = document.getElementById('produto_nome').value;
    alert(pd_id+' - '+pd_nome);
      }
   </script>";
```

O Alert esta retomando corretamente os valores dos select selecionado.

O problema vem agora, como fazer para a URL alterar automaticamente conforme o valor selecionado no select.

```
echo "<select id='produto_nome' name='produto_nome[]' value='' onchange='PegarValores()'>
<option value='-1'>
    Selecione
</option>";

while ($proteina = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    extract($proteina);
    echo '<option value="' . $produto_id . '">' . $produto_nome . '</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<a href='addtocart.php?id='$produto_id&name=$produto_nome' class='customButton'>";
echo "Adicionar";
echo "</a>";
```

Comment: Possível duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14646/como-selecionar-uma-opcao-em-um-select-e-carregar-dados-relacionados-em-outro

Comment: você quer apenas alterar a url adicionando no histórico ou quer mesmo redireccionar para a url pretendida?

Comment: Eu preciso que esses valores recolhidos, vá para a URL, para que possa ser adicionado a lista de pedidos. Eu apenas não sei como passar esses valores que estão da pd_id e pd_nome para a url no lugar de 'id='$produto_id&name=$produto_nome''

Answer (score 2):

Veja este exemplo aqui usando jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/zTrhX/

HTML:

```
<select id='meu_select'>
  <option value='1'>Valor 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Valor 2</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
// pega instância do select
var meu_select = $('#meu_select');
// adiciona evento quando o usuário selecionar outro valor
meu_select.change(function() {
  // pega valor do option selecionado
  var valor = meu_select.val()
  alert('Seu valor é: ' + valor);
  // muda url do navegador
  location.href = '#?param1=' + valor;
})
```