# Alterar url da barra de endereços sem atualizar a página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde um formulário com uma série de `<select>` enviam informações para um gráfico carregado via AJAX.

Gostaria que esses filtros refletissem na url do navegador, para facilitar ao usuário favoritar o filtro mais usado.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // MyChart("tipo do gráfico", "nome interno grafico", "widht", "heigth", "transparência")   
    var chart = new MyChart("Charts/tipo_do_grafico.swf", "MyChart", "100%", "700", "0");

    var refreshChart = function(){
        var urlParam = $("#filterForm").serialize();
        location.href = "#?" + urlParam;                    
        chart.setDataURL("rota/aplicacao/condicao1/condicao2?" + urlParam);
    };

    refreshChart();
    chart.render("divChart");

    $('#filterForm').change(refreshChart);

</script>
```

Com esse código consegui passar os valores que são enviadas via query string (`GET`) do formulário na url, passando um `#` para não atualizar a página (retirado [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15568/4751)).

```
location.href = "#?" + urlParam;
```

Porém como utilizo um sistema de rotas na minha aplicação, (`rota/condicao1/condicao2`) algumas condições ficam na URL e alterando elas no `location.href` minha página é atualizada.

---

Existe alguma forma de alterar **somente** a URL da barra de endereços via javascript, sem atualizar a página?

Se possível algo que funcione no Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Com HTML5 pode-se usar

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

Leia esse artigo para mais detalhes: [HTML5: Changing the browser-URL without refreshing page](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/)

Comment: Sabe se o IE suporta esse recurso ?

Comment: De acordo com o [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=history) a partir do 10 é suportado.

Comment: E sem HTML5, apenas com JQuery é possível?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Aí seria mais interessante usar o plugin [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js)