# transformar url Query String para uma url Legivel para o usuário

Tags: htaccess, url, querystring

Alguma vez notei que era possível transformar uma query string em algo mais legivel para o usuário, como isso:

real url:

```
site.com/roupas?categoria=vestidos
```

para isso(o que o usuário enxerga)

```
site.com/roupas/vestidos ou site.com/roupas/categoria/vestidos
```

Eu sei também que o caminho é pelo htaccess e têm que entender de REGEXR para fazer algo +- assim, mas preciso de um ponta pé para entender como fazer esse processo, se possível transformar em legivel a URL abaixo apenas para exemplificação:

```
site.com/roupas?categoria=vestidos
```

**E outra,..** com essa transformação, isso não vai atrapalhar na hora que eu quiser pegar o parametro por GET né? Ou seja, é só a parte visual que muda e a funcional não?..

Answer (score 1):

Quando você usa a url com o simbolo "?" o que vem depois são parâmetros $_GET. Também sei que é possível alterar a url via javascript, então sim é possível deixar a url mais "legível" para o usuário, porém você deve utilizar as variáveis que vem do $_GET primeiro e posteriormente mudar a url com javascript ai sim não vai te atrapalhar na hora de usar as variáveis que vem na url.

um exemplo com javascript é o comando

window.history.pushState()

que caí na pergunta [Alterar url da barra de endereços sem atualizar a página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32184/alterar-url-da-barra-de-endere%C3%A7os-sem-atualizar-a-p%C3%A1gina)