# Combobox + UF + Cidade + MySql + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp

Estou com a seguinte dúvida:
Tenho um projeto em Java JSP e nao sei como faço para selecionar o combo da UF e o de Cidade atualize conforme o que selecionei antes. abaixo eu tenho um exemplo com dados fixos, mas quero fazer em mysql, quero saber como que faço pra executar o select na tabela do banco. preciso de um exemplo no meu projeto

Já fiz de tudo que é forma e não sei como avançar.

tenho isso daqui feito no meu.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = function () {
        BindEvent();
    }
    function BindEvent()
    {
        var elemToBind = document.getElementById("uf");
        elemToBind.onchange = function () {
            SetSel(this);
        }
    }
    function SetSel(elem)
    {
        var secondCombo = document.getElementById("cidade");
        secondCombo.value = elem.value;
    }
</script>
<body>
    <select id="uf">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <select id="cidade">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

vi que nesse outro tópico existe o que preciso mas não sei php
precisava fazer funcionar com o jsp e fazendo a consulta no banco certinho

[Como selecionar uma opção em um <select> e carregar dados relacionados em outro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14646/como-selecionar-uma-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-um-select-e-carregar-dados-relacionados-em-outro)

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow! Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor como funciona essa comunidade. Em seguida, [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/56555/edit) a sua pergunta explique melhor quais são as suas dúvidas.

Comment: Cristiano vais precisar de usar AJAX (sabes o que é?) ou gerar a página com todas as possibilidades num objeto para usar no JavaScript para popular esse segundo select. Qual queres fazer?

Comment: Sei o que é mas nunca utilizei, nem sei como que o chamo por dentro do jsp. Precisaria de um exemplo pra mim ter noção de como dar inicio

Comment: Conseguiu Resolver?