# Input com estados do brasil e ao selecionar mostrar cidades desse estado

Tags: javascript, html

Bom, basicamente eu tenho o seguinte código com todos os Estados do Brasil.

```
<select name="estado"> 
    <option value="estado">Selecione o Estado</option> 
    <option value="ac">Acre</option> 
    <option value="al">Alagoas</option> 
    <option value="am">Amazonas</option> 
    <option value="ap">Amapá</option> 
    <option value="ba">Bahia</option> 
    <option value="ce">Ceará</option> 
    <option value="df">Distrito Federal</option> 
    <option value="es">Espírito Santo</option> 
    <option value="go">Goiás</option> 
    <option value="ma">Maranhão</option> 
    <option value="mt">Mato Grosso</option> 
    <option value="ms">Mato Grosso do Sul</option> 
    <option value="mg">Minas Gerais</option> 
    <option value="pa">Pará</option> 
    <option value="pb">Paraíba</option> 
    <option value="pr">Paraná</option> 
    <option value="pe">Pernambuco</option> 
    <option value="pi">Piauí</option> 
    <option value="rj">Rio de Janeiro</option> 
    <option value="rn">Rio Grande do Norte</option> 
    <option value="ro">Rondônia</option> 
    <option value="rs">Rio Grande do Sul</option> 
    <option value="rr">Roraima</option> 
    <option value="sc">Santa Catarina</option> 
    <option value="se">Sergipe</option> 
    <option value="sp">São Paulo</option> 
    <option value="to">Tocantins</option> 
</select>
<br>
<select name="cidades">
<option value="cidade1">Cidade 1</option> 
</select>
```

O que pretendia era fazer um javascript que ao selecionar um dos estados, aparecesse todas as cidades desse estado no select "cidades". Ou seja dependendo da escola do option estado, exibirá valores diferentes no select cidades.

Como poderei fazer isso?

Comment: De onde virão os dados sobre as cidades?

Comment: Eu coloco nos selects, só quero 1 javascript q faça 1 condição, caso seja aquele estado, aparece x cidade.

Comment: [Como selecionar uma opção em um `<select>` e carregar dados relacionados em outro?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14646/4808)

Comment: cara, olha neste post, respondi isso para uma outra pessoa, veja se te ajuda....eu fiz com JS puro mesmo....
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120759/como-fazer-um-select-html-carregar-uma-lista-de-op%C3%A7%C3%B5es-cada-vez-que-outro-select/120772#120772

Comment: É isso mesmo, só que eu quero com 3 parametros, ou seja 2 subdivisões.

Answer (score 1):

Selecione Rondônia, Maranhão ou São Paulo. É só um exemplo de como você poderia proceder, vendo que as cidades não são tão bem definidas como os estados, e são milhares.

```js
$('[name="estado"]').click(function(){

// ocultando todas
$('[name="cidades"] option').css('display', 'none');
 
// exibindo as do estado selecionado
$('[name="cidades"] .' + $(this).val()).css('display', '');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="estado"> 
    <option value="estado">Selecione o Estado</option> 
    <option value="ac">Acre</option> 
    <option value="al">Alagoas</option> 
    <option value="am">Amazonas</option> 
    <option value="ap">Amapá</option> 
    <option value="ba">Bahia</option> 
    <option value="ce">Ceará</option> 
    <option value="df">Distrito Federal</option> 
    <option value="es">Espírito Santo</option> 
    <option value="go">Goiás</option> 
    <option value="ma">Maranhão</option> 
    <option value="mt">Mato Grosso</option> 
    <option value="ms">Mato Grosso do Sul</option> 
    <option value="mg">Minas Gerais</option> 
    <option value="pa">Pará</option> 
    <option value="pb">Paraíba</option> 
    <option value="pr">Paraná</option> 
    <option value="pe">Pernambuco</option> 
    <option value="pi">Piauí</option> 
    <option value="rj">Rio de Janeiro</option> 
    <option value="rn">Rio Grande do Norte</option> 
    <option value="ro">Rondônia</option> 
    <option value="rs">Rio Grande do Sul</option> 
    <option value="rr">Roraima</option> 
    <option value="sc">Santa Catarina</option> 
    <option value="se">Sergipe</option> 
    <option value="sp">São Paulo</option> 
    <option value="to">Tocantins</option> 
</select>
<br>
<select name="cidades">
<option class="ma" value="cidade1">Cidade 1</option> 
  <option class="ma" value="cidade1">Cidade 2</option> 
  <option class="sp" value="cidade1">Cidade 3</option> 
  <option class="ro"  value="cidade1">Cidade 4</option> 
  <option class="ro" value="cidade1">Cidade 5</option> 
  <option class="ma" value="cidade1">Cidade 6</option> 
  <option class="sp" value="cidade1">Cidade 7</option> 
  <option class="ro" value="cidade1">Cidade 8</option> 
  <option class="sp" value="cidade1">Cidade 9</option> 
</select>
```