# Como fazer um combobox inserir texto dependendo da escolha?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Estou usando a ajuda de um post [aqui do SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14646/como-selecionar-uma-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-um-select-e-carregar-dados-relacionados-em-outro).

A diferença é que ao invés de ter várias opções para escolher no outro combobox, eu só tenho uma opção no banco, que já deve ser inserida no input, quando selecionar o relacionado.

O código que estou usando:

```
<?php include 'conn.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Combos Dependentes</title>
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="CmbUF"> 
    <option value="">Selecione a UF</option>
    <?php
        foreach($pdo->query('SELECT ufid, uf FROM ufs order by uf') as $row){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['ufid'].'">'.$row['uf'].'</option>';
        }       
    ?>
</select>
<select id="CmbCidade"> 
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#CmbUF').change(function(e) {
            $('#CmbCidade').empty();
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.post('call_cidades.php', {ufid:id}, function(data){
                var cmb = '<option value="">Selecione a Cidade</option>';
                $.each(data, function (index, value){
                    cmb = cmb + '<option value="' + value.cidadeid + '">' + value.cidade + '</option>';;
                });
                $('#CmbCidade').html(cmb);
            }, 'json');
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

DO Call Cidades.php:

```
<?php       
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) && $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] === "XMLHttpRequest"){
        include 'conn.php';
        $ufid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ufid', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        if ($ufid){
            $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT cidadeid, cidade FROM cidades where ufid=? ORDER BY cidade');
            $query->bindParam(1, $ufid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->execute();          
            echo json_encode($query->fetchAll());
            return;
        }       
    }
    echo NULL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa `$('#valor').val(JSON.stringify(data));` para setar o valor do input para uma string json.

- `$('#valor')` seleciona o input
- `.val(...)` seta o valor
- `JSON.stringify(data)` transforma o objeto em string.

Se queres aceder a uma propriedade desse objeto podes fazer por exemplo

```
$('#valor').val(data.valorContrato);
```