# Como atribuir valor ao campo input apos selecionar item no Select

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho um campo select com uma lista de nomes, apos selecionar um deles tenho de atribuir um valor no banco a um campo input.

[image: Esquema]

Comment: `jquery` ou `vanilla` mesmo?

Comment: _"atribuir um valor no banco a um campo input"_ - podes explicar melhor essa parte?

Comment: você tem que atribuir o valor que foi selecionado no campo select ao input também ? É isto ?

Comment: Sim. Tenho de varre o banco (select * from bancoTeste where $valor='campoescolhico')

Comment: no campo input tenho de atribuir esse valor!

Comment: Bom se for como estou pensando, com javascript isso se resolve, pois a medida que selecionar o value dentro do select ele preenche o campo input que você necessita com esse value respectivo

Comment: algum exemplo, passo-a-passo ou estudo de caso ?

Comment: criei uma resposta para isso, se lhe atender me de um feedback marcando como melhor resposta

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68711/discussion-between-victor-and-alexjosesilva).

Comment: Você quer pesquisar pelo nome ou por algum código do nome?

Comment: Veja se este link ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14646/66203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você quer pegar o `value` do seu campo `select` e jogar para um campo `input` caso não seja isso, comente que eu edito a resposta para adequar melhor

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('change', '.get-placa', function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $('.close').trigger('click');
            $('.campo2').val(value);
        });
</script>

<div class="col-lg-3">
    <select class="form-control get-placa" type="text"  name="campo1" maxlength='4'>
        <option></option>
        <option value='Campo1'>Campo1</option>
        <option value='Campo2'>Campo2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3">
    <label for="ex1">Pegando Value do Select:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control campo2" maxlength="14"  name="campo2"><br><!-- Input CNPJ -->
</div>
```

Comment: pegar o value do seu campo select e jogar para um campo input, isso mesmo...corretíssimo!