# PHP e JS - Como criar um form com sub selects

Tags: php

O meu plano é criar um formulário onde tenha 2 *selects*. No *select* #1 terá nomes transferidos através do MySQL. Ao escolher o nome pretendido do *select* 1#, automaticamente mostra dados do nome pretendido.

Exemplo

```
#1 select: joao, ruben
Selecionado: joao

#2 select:
Caso escolha o #1 joao: giro, feio, gordo etc
Caso escolha o #1 ruben: - gordinho, inteligente, lalalal
```

Existe alguma forma criada por ai?

Comment: Outra: [Como selecionar uma opção em um <select> e carregar dados relacionados em outro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14646/5878)

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar dois selects: o primeiro para o nome da pessoa, o segundo para as características. O segundo começa invisível (display: none(no css) ou .hide()(no function() do jquery))
Quando o val() do primeiro existir, o segundo aparece (.show()). A função que vai dar esse .show(), terá um if para identificar o valor do primeiro select. Dependendo de qual for, o segundo receberá as características corretas adicionadas na forma: $("#primeiroInput").html('blablabla')